# Global site salt, is it worth it?

Tags: security, salt, password-hash

I'm making a user database and I was thinking about security and it just made me think, is it really worth it to have a site salt when I'm going to have unique user salts on everybody.

```
md5(GLOBAL_SALT . $password . $user_salt);
```

vs

```
md5($password . $user_salt);
```

My thoughts is if the site were to get hacked the hackers would have access to the global salt anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is also called **pepper**. Salt and pepper have a different purpose:

- The salt prevents from rainbow-table attacks.
- The pepper can in some circumstances protect against dictionary attacks.

It actually depends upon whether the attacker has control over the server, or has only acces to the database (SQL-injection), if a pepper is of use. I recently wrote a tutorial about [hashing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/hash.html), where i tried to explain the important points.

There are other things to consider, like the fact that MD5 is ways too fast for password hashing, instead one should use a key derivation function like **BCrypt**.